# UIWebView in UITableView loses text

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview

I just changed my tableview to read rich text rather than plain text, so my solution was to load the rich text into a UIWebview, then add the webview to the tableview cell contentview.
However, with this change the text no longer displays at all. Here is the code for -cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellTVIdentifier = @"CellTVIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTVIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:CellTVIdentifier]
                autorelease];
    }

    int row = indexPath.row;

    NSString *cellString = [theArray objectAtIndex:row];

    // replaced    cell.textLabel.text=cellString;       
    // with

    UIWebView *webTVCell = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [webTVCell loadHTMLString:cellString baseURL:nil];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:webTVCell];
    [webTVCell release];

    return cell;
```

However, the text in cellString no longer appears in any cells of the tableview. Can anybody help? It would be muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIWebView *webTVCell = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
```

try this instead of `UIWebView *webTVCell = [[UIWebView alloc] init];`

`UIWebView` isn’t designed to work inside another scroller (like UITableView);

And to resize the cell you should use either `UITableView.rowHeight` property or the following `UITableViewDelegate` method :

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

And by the way, `[UITableView reloadData]` is normally a bad decision for updating the table.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! But now there's still one problem: I sized each cell in -heightForRowAtIndexPath, so the tableviewcells have the appropriate height. But the webview only displays about half of the content; I can scroll down to the rest of the text, but it is hidden by the bottom of the cell. Is there a way for the webview to fill the content of each cell, instead of scrolling? Thanks for your help.

Comment: [webTVCell setScalesPageToFit:YES];

Comment: That set the size of the text so miniscule that it is unreadable; also, I set the background color of the tableviewcells, but the text area is grey, with the rest of the cell the color I specified.

Comment: Hi Madhu, I originally had UIWebView *webTVCell = [[UIWebView alloc] init]; but the text was not showing up at all; before I was using  webview, I was getting the correct height for the cells by using -heightForRowAtIndexPath; when I pursued the webview solution, all this went out the window. ALso, don't understand your comment about [UITableView reloadData]; I am not using that method. All I am trying to do is use the webview so I can render rich text within the tableviewcells; that's why I am attempting to use uiwebview.

Comment: With [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds], only part of the webview displays in the cell, like it is behind the rest of the cell.

Comment: What I really want is to display rich text, since the file I am reading has html tags embedded. If there's another (easier?) way to render rich text in a tableviewcell, I'd pursue it, but I don't know how to do that.